# Is it right to call the values produced by emmeans coefficicents?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, lsmeans

I have a logistic regression model with a categorical predictor with five levels.

I compute emmeans for the model, splitting by my categorical predictor.

```
emms <- emmeans(m_final, "Factor")
```

Then I compare these to chance.

```
test(emms, null = 0)
```

My output looks like this:

```
 Factor  emmean    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 A      -0.0787 0.110 Inf  -0.714  0.4754
 B       0.2217 0.111 Inf   1.999  0.0456
etc
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale.
```

**Would it be right to call the values in the emmean column: coefficients comparing levels of a factor to chance, computed using marginal means.**

Comment: I would not call them coefficients. That would be misleading. I would call them estimated marginal means.

Comment: not coefficients. then are predicted marginal means in the case of fixed effects, and best unbiased linear predictors (BULPs) in the case of random effects

Comment: @Roland Do you want to make your comment into an answer?